# Inserção de dados no BD com codeigniter em tabelas diferentes no mesmo controller

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados, um formulário com os campos da tabela1 e tabela2! a inserção dos campos da tabela1 estão ocorrendo normalmente, no entanto, a inserção da tabela2 não está ocorrendo!Simplesmente não cadastra!

Meu controller:

```
public function cadastrar(){
    esta_logado();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'NOME', 'trim|required|ucwords');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'EMAIL', 'trim|valid_email|is_unique[pessoa.email]|strtolower');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpf', 'CPF', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('rg', 'RG', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefone', 'TELEFONE', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('rua', 'RUA', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('numero', 'NÚMERO', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bairro', 'BAIRRO', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('complemento', 'COMPLEMENTO', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cidade', 'CIDADE', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('estado', 'ESTADO', 'trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE):
        $dados = elements(array('nome', 'email', 'cpf', 'rg', 'telefone'), $this->input->post());
        $this->cidadao->do_insert_cidadao($dados);   
        $dados = elements(array('rua', 'numero', 'bairro', 'complemento', 'cidade', 'estado'), $this->input->post());   
        $this->endereco->do_insert_endereco($dados);    
    endif;
```

primeiro model:

```
Class Cidadao_model extends CI_model{

public function do_insert_cidadao($dados = NULL, $redir = TRUE){
    if($dados != NULL):
        $this->db->insert('pessoa', $dados);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0):
        set_msg('msgok', 'Cadastro efeutado com sucesso!', 'sucesso');
        else:
        set_msg('msgerro', 'Erro ao inerir dados!', 'erro');
        endif;
    if($redir) redirect(current_url()); //Irá da um refresh na página
    endif;


}
```

Segundo model:

```
Class Endereco_model extends CI_model{

public function do_insert_endereco($dados = NULL, $redir = TRUE){
    if($dados != NULL):
        $this->db->insert('endereco', $dados);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0):
        set_msg('msgok', 'Cadastro efeutado com sucesso!', 'sucesso');
        else:
        set_msg('msgerro', 'Erro ao inerir dados!', 'erro');
        endif;
    if($redir) redirect(current_url()); //Irá da um refresh na página
    endif;


}
```

As minhas funções de insert's estão em models diferentes, criei também no mesmo model as funções de insert's, mas não funcionou também!

Por que não consigo inserir dados na outra tabela?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vi seu primeiro insert esta redirecionando o usuário apos a inserção, mude a chamada do metodo da seguinte forma

```
$this->cidadao->do_insert_cidadao($dados, FALSE);
```

Porque seu metodo de insersão de cidadão já tem um recurso de redirecionamento automático ou não.

via de regra, o usuário só pode ser redirecionado ou atualizar a página apos as duas inserções.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, problema era redirecionamento mesmo!